# SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE does not work if program is minimized by clicking the taskbar button

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My application can receive a message from another application. If the app is minimized, I want to restore it to the previous state without giving focus to it.

I'm doing it by calling

```
::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

It works well if the app was minimized using the Minimize button in the title bar, but if the app was minimized by clicking its button in the Windows task bar, then the app will receive focus.

Can this be fixed or worked around?

Comment: So actually it does work, but you want it to behave differently?

Comment: Just a quick thing to be tested. Can you make one button on the UI and add the code to minimize the window manually i.e. `::ShowWindow(.., SW_MINIMIZE);`

Comment: Try `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);` and see if it behaves differently.

Comment: @MarkJansen: It does not work correctly, if the app was minimized using the taskbar button. In this case the window is restored and brought to top. If the window was minimized using the Minimize button, then the window is just restored but not brought to top, which is how the SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE should work in both cases.

Comment: @hypheni: It works OK in that case, the same way as when the Minimize button of the title bar is clicked. But how does that help?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: It's not OK. I want to show the window without bringing it to top. SC_RESTORE is not good for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following `HWND hwndForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow()` before your `ShowWindow` function call. Afterwards you can restore the foreground window with `SetForegroundWindow(hwndForegroundWindow)`. It depends on what you mean with focus though, foreground window and focus are something different (For element focus use `GetFocus` and `SetFocus`).

Comment: This could be a workaround, but it still brings the window to z-order top-1. So it doesn't work the same as when the window was minimized using the Minimize button, but at least the last active window is on top.

Comment: Why not set a boolean at `SC_MINIMIZE` or `SW_SIZE` events (and unset it every time the window gets focus)? Then before your `ShowWindow` call you can check which window has focus and reset it afterwards in your window was not minimized by such event.
I'm not sure what you mean with minimized by the taskbar, but look into the win32 Window Proc events. I'm sure you can nail down specific cases with those.